# File not deleted Android

Tags: android, kotlin, file, gridview, fragment

I want to delete file from specific folder

I have this code in a fragment

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/MyDir/Filename.jpg")
if(file.exists()){
     try {
          val delete = file.delete()
          if(delete){
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }else{
               Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"KO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
     }catch (e:Exception){
          Toast.makeText(requireContext(),e.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
     }
}
```

Always shows "KO" in toast (delete is always false), file exists and write permission granted (this code is into permission_granted section)
what am I doing wrong?
I have tried many solutions from other posts but none have worked for me

- canonical file
- different routes (the one I put in the example is the only one that goes into file.exists())
  thanks for your time

Comment: Who put that file in MyDir?

Comment: Which Android version on used device?

Comment: was that file created by your application? In case it was, did you close the file writer before trying to delete it?